# How can I throw exceptions in set-body in Azure API Management?

Tags: azure-api-management

The API that I'm working on now throwing 500 Internal Server Error when the request body do not have certain property inside. I want to eliminate that and instead, it returns another status code such as 400 Bad Request. I get that the error is return from APIM from Azure, how can I throw the error inside the set-body policy since I deserialize the request body in here?

I've read many posts and documents but no luck on succeeding that. Here's my code right now:

```
<inbound>
        <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="" timeout="60 sec">
            <set-method>POST</set-method>
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>@{
                var request = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true);
                if(String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)request["id"])){
                    WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?
                }
                return request.ToString();
            }</set-body>
        </send-request>
</inbound>
```

Thanks and appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the return response policy in Azure API Management 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#ReturnResponse

Comment: Thanks! I'd figured that out much later, thanks for the link provided!

Comment: No problem, my pleasure.